# Best Circuit Design for a 12VDC Wall-Wart > Ouput Voltage of 1.5V (Replacing Alkaline Batteries)

Tags: dc, batteries, voltage-regulator

I have multiple stationary baby items for my son Oliver that require a serious supply of batteries each month. I would like to hook a few of these stationary items up to wall warts to conserve the constant expense of alkaline purchase/recharging of batteries. I currently have two spare wall warts laying around the house: first at 9V/1A and the second at 12V/1A. I am located 15km from a Mouser warehouse in case the garage will not suffice.

Two items I would like to wire up right now include a baby rocker which requires one D battery and a crib which includes a mobile electronic toy rotation device requiring 3 AA batteries.

I was lucky enough to get these from a baby shower and due to my current job situation, I can't upgrade. I would like to build a circuit for both but will discuss the baby rocker at this point.

This circuit would need to accept either voltage from the wall warts and drop it to 1.5V to run the baby rocker's vibrator. I have been looking at the 780x type linear regulators at this point but am not sure if this is the way to go. I wanted to see what you might recommend. I need advice that will not only eliminate batteries, hopefully save electricity, and also be easy to solder as I do not have the skills and equipment for SMD applications.

Thx in advance for your help!

Comment: a time consuming, but inexpensive thing would be to re-wind the coil in the rocker with lighter gauge wire so that instead of slugs of current at 1.5V, it would operate on less current at 9V.  not very glamorous, borders on the mechanical, but in theory it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm surprised the rocker doesn't have a DC inlet already.

You could connect the 9 V supply to a linear 1.5 V regulator, and it would be easy, but you'd be wasting a lot of energy.  It would be better to just go to a thrift store and try to find wall warts that are close (more appropriate transformer turns ratio) to the voltage you need.  Regulating a 3.3 V or 5 V supply down to 1.5 V would be more efficient.  The voltage might not even need regulating, or could be anywhere within a large range and still work, but you'd have to take the products apart and see what they feed into.  I ruined a digital camera by accidentally using a higher voltage adapter, but many things don't care.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be willing to bet the rocker doesn't really have any electronics anyways (probably just a switched coil/magnet).  I'd probably (check my earlier assumption first, then) grab some old cell-phone charger, chop the end off, and wire it up and see what happens.  Only problem might be that the current is higher than it should be and it heats up (catches fire, and burns your house down).

Comment: You don't need to worry about the current rating on the power supply, as long as it is higher than what you need. It simply lists a maximum amount it can supply, it's not saying that whatever you connect your 9V/1A adapter to, will have 1 amp of current "pushed" through it.

Comment: I can't believe it doesn't have a inlet either. This sounds like the way to roll. Thanks all!

Comment: I've actually come across a 1.2V supply for slow charging Ni-MH batteries. Have a look at one of those. It's quite likely that 1.2V will satisfactorily run it.

Comment: Baby equipment almost never has a DC inlet aka strangle cord and very often runs on 3 inconvenient batteries. This kind of "rocker" is just a little chair with an oversized cellphone vibrate motor and a switch.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to get a couple of rechargeable batteries and a charger, that will solve your problem... but it is a boring answer.

The second is to use a switched regulator, but I don't know any good one that can be soldered by hand so...

Comment: Problem is the rechargeables are being switched out quite quickly to where my Excel spreadsheet tells me they won't even last two years. Am sure this is bad circuit design. Would really like to look into AC powered possibilities. Although, I will mention that a recharge circuit for a rechargeable battery in the rocker would definitely suite my needs.